403 Forbidden Error in Helpjuice API Request When Creating a User with Zapier Webhook
Steps I’ve Taken
Authorization: I generated my API key from Helpjuice, Base64-encoded it, and included it in the request header.
Payload: Here’s the JSON body I’m sending in the request:
Copy code
{
  "user": {
    "first_name": "customer first name",
    "last_name": "customer last name",
    "email": "customer email",
    "role_id": 0,
    "group_ids": [57416]
  }
}

Headers: I’ve set the Authorization header to use Basic Auth with my Base64-encoded API key, and I’ve also set Content-Type to application/json.
Helpjuice Settings:
I’ve enabled the API key and confirmed that the API access is turned on in Helpjuice.
My account has super admin permissions.
Error Received
When testing the request in Zapier, I receive the following error:

Error: 403 Forbidden
Message from API: {"exception":"Not allowed."}

Additional Context
I’ve confirmed the group ID (57416) and role ID (0) are valid in my Helpjuice setup.
Environment: I’m using Zapier to trigger the webhook, and I’ve tested the same payload in Postman and received the same 403 error.
What I’m Trying to Do
Goal: When a specific tag is added to a contact in Keap, I want Zapier to create a user in Helpjuice automatically.
API Endpoint: I’m using Helpjuice's POST /api/v3/users endpoint to create the user.

Have you checked the API permissions and authentication? If you're exploring alternatives, ByteChef might simplify your workflow with visual integrations and custom code capabilities. https://github.com/bytechefhq/bytechef

Looking at Helpjuice's Doc, it shows that the 403 response code happens when the authenticated user doesn't have access to the requested data.
You'll want to check to see if the API key has access to create a user.
